# Redux - update parents props via Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a dynamic router that takes routes as props of `<App>`. By default all routes are blocked and user can only go to `Payments`.

A few levels deep I have `<Payments>`. Once you do your first payment you should be able to access the whole app, in short:

```
<App> -> <OtherComponent> -> <OtherComponent> - <Payments>
```

I want to dispatch an action in `<Payments>` (grandchild) that will change redux state in `<App>` reducer and change `<App>` props (grandparent), how do I handle this? As far as I'm concerned I'm only allowed to mapStateToProps in `<Payments>` but the router is in `<App>`.

I'm using basic react-router and would rather not change it for anything else (eg. react-redux-router).

Comment: The entire application state is accessible to all the components and you could dispatch an action to update the state from anywhere and the relevant component will fetch it, that is the beauty of using a redux store over component state

Comment: You can connect every component that resides inside the redux `<Provider>` component and therefore also map the state to props of every component. That's actually the reason why you use redux. So just dispatch an action in your `<Payments>`component that alters the state and connect your `<App>`component to it.

Comment: Could you guys provide some examples please? I'm using react-redux with connect() yet I have no idea how to pass props to components above. Note my App and Payments components use separate reducers.

Comment: Redux's state can be considered to be application wide, as any (connected) component can dispatch actions and access application-level state, so it's really just a matter for you to define the proper objects and the relevant actions in Redux, and then make proper use of these objects at the component level - the hierarchy of your components is not really relevant (except for the passing down of props, but that's pretty standard).

Comment: You do not pass props from component to component. Instead you make a component dispatch an action that alters the global state and you connect every component to the store that need to get updates from the store. The redux documentation has plenty of examples.

Comment: @trixn that's the issue, I have separate reducers here, if I log "state" in PaymentsReducer is has access only to this reducers properties, thus I can't even check whats in AppReducer not mentioning updating it's state. (I'm not using Thunk btw)

Comment: Also if you consider reducers to belong to certain components you did not get the concept of redux right yet. You store is a single object that can hold arbitrary data and make that globally accessible by connecting components to it. A reducer does not belong to a certain component but is responsible for updating nested objects inside your store. It has nothing to do with components. Basically you could even use redux without react.

Comment: A redux store is more like a database. You keep information like users, profiles, products and so on. For each entity type you will usually have a nested object that has it's own reducer. Try not to think of components but of entities when you model your store.

Comment: I think I got the Redux part just right, the problem I have is CombineReducers, with one big flat state it would be easy peasy for me to do what I want to achieve but I feel like my state is now not truly global but split between 3 different reducers and they don't have access to each other.

Comment: Reducers do not need access to each other. Every reducer can listen to every action that you dispatch and update the part of the store that it is responsible for. After all reducers where run redux will then pass the changed data to the components that you have connected to your store. It will only pass new props to them if they actually changed.

Comment: "Every reducer can listen to every action that you dispatch" - I just realised I can link actions from my OTHER reducers (and parts of app) in ANY reducer file. Not sure if that's the best practice, but it indeed should work. Consider answering my question so I will be able to accept your answer and close the issue (once it works). Thanks a lot man! Not sure how Redux would react to two reducers listening to the same action type though but we will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I got the Redux part just right, the problem I have is
>   CombineReducers, with one big flat state it would be easy peasy for me
>   to do what I want to achieve but I feel like my state is now not truly
>   global but split between 3 different reducers and they don't have
>   access to each other.

You can safely listen to the same actions in multiple reducers. That's also good practice to do so. Imagine an action that has an impact in multiple places of your store. Every nested structure will have it's own reducer and therefore you will have to listen to that action in multiple reducers. That is totally fine.